# Solving Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the eigenfunctions of the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian.

This is my code:

```
NDEigensystem[
  {-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + 0.5 x^2 u[x], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, 
  u[x], x ∈ {-1000, 1000}, 4]
```

However *Mathematica* is returning my input as an output.
Suggestions on how to find the eigenfunctions?

Answer (score 5):

If you want solve for one variable you don't need `∈`:

```
NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + 0.5 x^2 u[x], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -1000, 1000}, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

`NDEigensystem` doesn't like `x ∈ {-1000, 1000}`. When I substitute `{x, -1000, 1000}`, I get

```
NDEigensystem[
 {-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + 0.5 x^2 u[x],
 DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]},
 u[x], {x, -1000, 1000}, 4]
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

The above answers actually return something, which is good though the results are a bit nonsensical. The actual eigenfunctions should have 0, 1, 2 and 3 nodes respectively. It looks like the range of x is too large and is causing artifacts. Try [-10,10] instead of [-1000,1000] i.e.

```
NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + 0.5 x^2 u[x], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -10, 10}, 4]
```

This gives the right eigenfunctions. Note that harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions is an example given in the Mathematica documentation for NDEigensystem under 'scope.'